# Connect two VMs on two different physical machines into their own network

Tags: networking, virtualbox

Right now I have a setup on the left: two physical machines connected via router, each with its own VirtualBox VM inside. They have bridged adapters, so they appear in the network, everyone sees everyone.

[image: Network setups]

I'd like to achieve setup on the right. The physical machines are left as-is but the VMs are connected into their own network, not depending on the router (I believe it must only act like switch) and not accessible from the physical machines. How to do that?

I couldn't find anything on this topic. It is possible I just don't know proper words. Or is it impossible? I apologise in advance if I just showed my ignorance in the topic but I'd really like to learn something.

Comment: I just started searching for it, too. I would in fact like two virtual machines (on separate hosts) be connected by a virtual LAN cable or by a virtual serial (null modem) cable and not (necessarily) see the actual network in which the hosts reside. Thinking about starting a bounty, but with 5 views so far that would be rather pointless...